# Don't run over your sister's foot / Don't crush your sister's foot / Ride on car context

Tags: word-choice, verbs

My son has this ride on car.

[image: Ride On Car]

How would a native say "don't crush your sister's foot"?

1. Don't run over your sister's foot!
2. Don't crush your sister's foot!
3. Don't crush your sister's foot with your car's wheels!
4. Don't let your car crush your sister's foot!
5. Don't run your sister's foot over!

Thank you.

Comment: If I were talking to a small child then something like your first suggestion would be what I would choose.

Comment: Is there a shorter phrase for it?

Comment: "Run over" is the standard term when describing a vehicle (including toys) driving or rolling over somebody.

Comment: @lekneh1209 - "Don't do that!!"

Comment: Any comment that includes the word *crush* implies that it's okay to hurt, but not crush. Your first choice is good English. None of your choices, however, tell your son what you want him to do, which is to drive without touching people. Saying no a lot in the first two years guarantees the classic Terrible Twos.